# A multiple choice question, with multiple or only one correct answer, and sometimes no correct answer

Tags: database-design, schema, relations

It's a question & answer based model, and here is the scenario:

1. A question with multiple choices given, with 3 to 7 correct answers among those choices.
2. A question with multiple choices given, with only one correct answer among those choices.
3. A question with no choices given, with only one correct answer, and the solver will have to come at that answer themselves.

What I have done so far:

`answers`:

- content (text-based column, length could be of 100 - 150 chars)
- question_id (foreign_key)
- correct_answer (boolean)

`questions`:

- id (primary key)
- content (text-based column, length could be of 100 - 150 chars)
- multiple_choice (boolean)

Having a column `multiple_choice`, so in case if it's false, it means the particular question will be given no choice, and the solver will have to provide the answer all by themselves.

Issue:

Given that an answer only has to store a string of few characters, a boolean of either correct or not, why can't/shouldn't I store it as datatype jsonb in the `questions` table?

Comment: Check this article out: https://dbsophic.com/learn-more/sql-server-articles/59-every-question-has-many-answers . Although it deals with a default answer, the same rules apply for a correct answer, so it may give you some ideas on how to design the schema.